# eclipse was closing when i try to open web.xml in web application what would be the reason?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, configuration, jvm

I am using Eclipse 3.6,
while opening `web.xml` file in my Web application.
it's crucial for me to open web.xml file multiple times while doing development.
eclipse.ini configuration was given below.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

How can we configure Eclipse, to perform well.

**Error Log Given Below:**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6613f47d, pid=5128, tid=2064
#
# JRE version: 6.0_22-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [gdiplus.dll+0xf47d]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x003a6c00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=2064, stack(0x009c0000,0x00a10000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0xa96074a8

Registers:
EAX=0xffffffff, EBX=0x66370060, ECX=0x00000002, EDX=0x000000ff
ESP=0x00a0e32c, EBP=0x00a0e340, ESI=0xa96074a8, EDI=0xa96074a8
EIP=0x6613f47d, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00a0e32c)
0x00a0e32c:   662f2d78 662f2db0 00000001 a96074a8
0x00a0e33c:   a96074a8 00a0e35c 6613f008 00000002
0x00a0e34c:   66370060 a96074a8 662f2d60 0000012a
0x00a0e35c:   00a0e3b4 66209b8a a96074a8 66370060
0x00a0e36c:   00000002 0000012a 0000008e 00000000
0x00a0e37c:   662f8748 662f2d60 a94eb000 662f2d60
0x00a0e38c:   a94eb000 00000004 00000000 00000000
0x00a0e39c:   00000002 00000000 00000004 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x6613f47d)
0x6613f46d:   ff 76 10 8b 01 ff 50 04 c7 06 46 41 49 4c 5e c3
0x6613f47d:   89 07 e9 1d fc ff ff 90 90 90 90 90 8b ff 55 8b 


Stack: [0x009c0000,0x00a10000],  sp=0x00a0e32c,  free space=13800a0de60k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xf47d]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xf008]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xd9b8a]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xd9d3f]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0x78f64]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0x12365]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xf475]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0x43188]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xe6409]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0x417ba]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0x41778]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xb3737]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xa099d]
C  [gdiplus.dll+0xa0aab]
C  [swt-gdip-win32-3650.dll+0x537e]
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gdip.Gdip.Graphics_FillPolygon(II[III)I+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.fillPolygon([I)V+74
j  org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section.onPaint(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/PaintEvent;)V+635
j  org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite$1.paintControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/PaintEvent;)V+5
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;Z)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PAINT(II)Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/LRESULT;+1429
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(IIII)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(IIII)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(IIII)I
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3a9c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x186591]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3b1d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfd5af]
V  [jvm.dll+0xff3d7]
C  [swt-win32-3650.dll+0x122f]
C  0x66100018
C  [USER32.dll+0x8734]
C  [USER32.dll+0x8816]
C  [USER32.dll+0x18ea0]
C  [USER32.dll+0x18eec]
C  [ntdll.dll+0xe473]
C  [USER32.dll+0x8a10]
C  [xul.dll+0x51a909]
C  [xul.dll+0x51a453]
C  [xul.dll+0x5a0aaf]
C  [xul.dll+0x586fa9]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gdip.Gdip.Graphics_FillPolygon(II[III)I+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.fillPolygon([I)V+74
j  org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section.onPaint(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/PaintEvent;)V+635
j  org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite$1.paintControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/PaintEvent;)V+5
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;Z)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PAINT(II)Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/LRESULT;+1429
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(IIII)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(IIII)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(IIII)I
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/MSG;)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z
J  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/jface/window/Window$IExceptionHandler;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;)V
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI()I+555
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Workbench;)I+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run()V+55
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+99
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x68d28800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4420, stack(0x706f0000,0x70740000)]
  0x68667400 JavaThread "Worker-49" [_thread_blocked, id=960, stack(0x6edb0000,0x6ee00000)]
  0x67225800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2256, stack(0x6d490000,0x6d4e0000)]
  0x68047400 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1096, stack(0x6bb80000,0x6bbd0000)]
  0x6713a800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4840, stack(0x6dcf0000,0x6dd40000)]
  0x652a8c00 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=5668, stack(0x6dc40000,0x6dc90000)]
  0x65927400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=5848, stack(0x6dbf0000,0x6dc40000)]
  0x6722f000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=2440, stack(0x6dba0000,0x6dbf0000)]
  0x65b5a400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=204, stack(0x6d340000,0x6d390000)]
  0x6716c400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5692, stack(0x6c830000,0x6c880000)]
  0x67025400 JavaThread "Worker-47" [_thread_blocked, id=664, stack(0x6d780000,0x6d7d0000)]
  0x683fa400 JavaThread "Worker-44" [_thread_blocked, id=5620, stack(0x6d600000,0x6d650000)]
  0x652cf000 JavaThread "Worker-42" [_thread_blocked, id=5812, stack(0x6d560000,0x6d5b0000)]
  0x6709b400 JavaThread "Worker-40" [_thread_blocked, id=5464, stack(0x6d440000,0x6d490000)]
  0x67221800 JavaThread "Worker-34" [_thread_blocked, id=5840, stack(0x6d030000,0x6d080000)]
  0x65a94800 JavaThread "Worker-26" [_thread_blocked, id=2236, stack(0x6cda0000,0x6cdf0000)]
  0x6744e800 JavaThread "Worker-20" [_thread_blocked, id=5456, stack(0x6cab0000,0x6cb00000)]
  0x66cad800 JavaThread "Background Startup" [_thread_blocked, id=3736, stack(0x6c140000,0x6c190000)]
  0x67002c00 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=5196, stack(0x6bae0000,0x6bb30000)]
  0x67001c00 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=6048, stack(0x6b2b0000,0x6b300000)]
  0x66d15400 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3984, stack(0x6b260000,0x6b2b0000)]
  0x67031000 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=5384, stack(0x6b090000,0x6b0e0000)]
  0x68354400 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4832, stack(0x6a7c0000,0x6a810000)]
  0x65ab0400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5552, stack(0x67720000,0x67770000)]
  0x65ab2400 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4868, stack(0x67980000,0x679d0000)]
  0x65af9000 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4448, stack(0x675c0000,0x67610000)]
  0x67382400 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5504, stack(0x67470000,0x674c0000)]
  0x65ae1800 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5796, stack(0x66c20000,0x66c70000)]
  0x651b4c00 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1452, stack(0x665c0000,0x66610000)]
  0x6534e400 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=4784, stack(0x65770000,0x657c0000)]
  0x652c1800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3584, stack(0x657c0000,0x65810000)]
  0x65261400 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4848, stack(0x65720000,0x65770000)]
  0x6522d800 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4688, stack(0x65630000,0x65680000)]
  0x6525d400 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3720, stack(0x655e0000,0x65630000)]
  0x64ea0000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5560, stack(0x650f0000,0x65140000)]
  0x64e9bc00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=940, stack(0x650a0000,0x650f0000)]
  0x64e98800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4904, stack(0x65050000,0x650a0000)]
  0x64e97400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4608, stack(0x65000000,0x65050000)]
  0x64e88400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5624, stack(0x64fb0000,0x65000000)]
  0x64e83800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4984, stack(0x64f60000,0x64fb0000)]
=>0x003a6c00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=2064, stack(0x009c0000,0x00a10000)]

Other Threads:
  0x64e81000 VMThread [stack: 0x64f10000,0x64f60000] [id=2864]
  0x64eaac00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x65140000,0x65190000] [id=4664]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 160000K, used 90361K [0x02a90000, 0x0d820000, 0x17fe0000)
  eden space 142272K,   0% used [0x02a90000, 0x07ad3d60, 0x0b580000)
  from space 17728K,  46% used [0x0c6d0000, 0x0ceca978, 0x0d820000)
  to   space 17728K,   0% used [0x0b580000, 0x0b580000, 0x0c6d0000)
 tenured generation   total 355212K, used 213125K [0x17fe0000, 0x2dac3000, 0x42a90000)
   the space 355212K,  59% used [0x17fe0000, 0x25001510, 0x25001600, 0x2dac3000)
 compacting perm gen  total 119808K, used 119613K [0x42a90000, 0x49f90000, 0x62a90000)
   the space 119808K,  99% used [0x42a90000, 0x49f5f7e8, 0x49f5f800, 0x49f90000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\javaw.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f03000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6db47000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d850000 - 0x6d85c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3d0000 - 0x6d3ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d338000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d890000 - 0x6d89f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x653a0000 - 0x653f5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6c3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x72000000 - 0x7200d000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20100503\eclipse_1307.dll
0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\COMCTL32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x654b0000 - 0x654e8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x65540000 - 0x6554e000     C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Real\RealPlayer\BrowserRecordPlugin\Chrome\Hook\rpchrome14browserrecordhelper.dll
0x78520000 - 0x785c3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_x-ww_d495ac4e\MSVCR90.dll
0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x78480000 - 0x7850e000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_x-ww_d495ac4e\MSVCP90.dll
0x74720000 - 0x7476c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x755c0000 - 0x755ee000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
0x774e0000 - 0x7761e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x6d6d0000 - 0x6d6d9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x77120000 - 0x771ab000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL
0x65c10000 - 0x65c73000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\564\1\.cp\swt-win32-3650.dll
0x763b0000 - 0x763f9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x74d90000 - 0x74dfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USP10.dll
0x65c80000 - 0x65d66000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WININET.dll
0x65710000 - 0x65719000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Normaliz.dll
0x78130000 - 0x78263000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\urlmon.dll
0x65da0000 - 0x65f8b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iertutil.dll
0x66110000 - 0x6612d000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\564\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3650.dll
0x66130000 - 0x662db000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.6002.22509_x-ww_c7dad023\gdiplus.dll
0x66360000 - 0x6636e000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\67\1\.cp\os\win32\x86\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x66730000 - 0x6676a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\oleacc.dll
0x668b0000 - 0x66b75000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll
0x77b40000 - 0x77b62000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Apphelp.dll
0x678d0000 - 0x67928000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71a90000 - 0x71a98000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6d830000 - 0x6d838000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x77a80000 - 0x77b15000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77b20000 - 0x77b32000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x76fd0000 - 0x7704f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
0x77050000 - 0x77115000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
0x75cf0000 - 0x75d81000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mlang.dll
0x6d0b0000 - 0x6d1fa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x73000000 - 0x73026000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x6d2e0000 - 0x6d32f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x67d90000 - 0x67da3000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\564\1\.cp\swt-xulrunner-win32-3650.dll
0x67db0000 - 0x67dd9000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\nspr4.dll
0x71ad0000 - 0x71ad9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x67de0000 - 0x67e91000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\MOZCRT19.dll
0x67fa0000 - 0x67fa7000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\plc4.dll
0x67fb0000 - 0x67fb7000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\plds4.dll
0x69040000 - 0x690ac000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\sqlite3.dll
0x67fc0000 - 0x67fd4000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\nssutil3.dll
0x690b0000 - 0x690d6000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\softokn3.dll
0x69450000 - 0x694ea000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\nss3.dll
0x67fe0000 - 0x68000000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\ssl3.dll
0x690e0000 - 0x690f8000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\smime3.dll
0x694f0000 - 0x695bb000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\js3250.dll
0x695c0000 - 0x69f00000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\xul.dll
0x76380000 - 0x76385000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x69400000 - 0x69407000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\xpcom.dll
0x77d00000 - 0x77d33000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netman.dll
0x76d40000 - 0x76d58000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MPRAPI.dll
0x77cc0000 - 0x77cf2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ACTIVEDS.dll
0x76e10000 - 0x76e35000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\adsldpc.dll
0x76b20000 - 0x76b31000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ATL.DLL
0x76e80000 - 0x76e8e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rtutils.dll
0x71bf0000 - 0x71c03000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SAMLIB.dll
0x77920000 - 0x77a13000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x76400000 - 0x765a5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netshell.dll
0x76c00000 - 0x76c2e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\credui.dll
0x69ff0000 - 0x69ffa000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dot3api.dll
0x736d0000 - 0x736d6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dot3dlg.dll
0x6a150000 - 0x6a178000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OneX.DLL
0x76f50000 - 0x76f58000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x76360000 - 0x76370000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSTA.dll
0x745b0000 - 0x745d2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\eappcfg.dll
0x76080000 - 0x760e5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCP60.dll
0x6a180000 - 0x6a18e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\eappprxy.dll
0x76ee0000 - 0x76f1c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RASAPI32.dll
0x76e90000 - 0x76ea2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasman.dll
0x76eb0000 - 0x76edf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\TAPI32.dll
0x73030000 - 0x73040000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WZCSAPI.DLL
0x7db10000 - 0x7db9c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WZCSvc.DLL
0x76d30000 - 0x76d34000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WMI.dll
0x7d4b0000 - 0x7d4d2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DHCPCSVC.DLL
0x72810000 - 0x7281b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\EapolQec.dll
0x726c0000 - 0x726d6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\QUtil.dll
0x6a190000 - 0x6a29d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ESENT.dll
0x6a740000 - 0x6a748000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_1.9.1.2\xulrunner\javaxpcomglue.dll
0x73ce0000 - 0x73d01000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\t2embed.dll
0x73dc0000 - 0x73dc3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\LZ32.dll
0x66500000 - 0x6650f000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\70\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x66520000 - 0x66579000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x6b980000 - 0x6b987000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\301\1\.cp\jnicrypt.dll
0x6c020000 - 0x6c0db000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
0x6eec0000 - 0x6eee2000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32_1.6.12\libapr-1.dll
0x6ee50000 - 0x6ee59000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32_1.6.12\libapriconv-1.dll
0x6c200000 - 0x6c308000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32_1.6.12\libeay32.dll
0x6c310000 - 0x6c346000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32_1.6.12\ssleay32.dll
0x6ee60000 - 0x6ee8f000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32_1.6.12\libaprutil-1.dll
0x6c350000 - 0x6c465000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32_1.6.12\dbghelp.dll
0x6c570000 - 0x6c583000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32_1.6.12\libsasl.dll
0x6c590000 - 0x6c63a000     D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32_1.6.12\libsvn_subr-1.dll
0x76780000 - 0x76789000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHFOLDER.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m 
java_command: D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -showsplash -launcher D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\eclipse.exe -name Eclipse --launcher.library D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20100503\eclipse_1307.dll -startup D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar -exitdata ccc_40 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -launcher.defaultAction openFile -vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/javaw.exe -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar D:\eclipse\Eclipse 3.6\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22
PATH=D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;
USERNAME=kakarlac
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 2059852k(372152k free), swap 8436304k(6594940k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_22-b04), built on Sep 15 2010 00:56:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Fri Oct 28 16:31:30 2011
elapsed time: 6626 seconds
```

This information is sufficient I think.

Comment: The information you give is not sufficient to deduce the problem. Please look at least in the error log.

Comment: On the off chance that the file is corrupt, can you open it in notepad or similar?

Comment: Does this happen repeatedly or was this a once-off crash? If the latter, restart Eclipse and carry on.

Comment: @PhilippReichart it's happening when ever i try to open web.xml file in my application. (repeatedly)

Comment: This is not the Eclipse bug tracker.  I'd to close as off topic, if i weren't out of votes today.  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the reason could be at all.
But here a couple of alternatives that might help:

1-Create a new clean project and see if the same happens. 
If so, there might be something wrong with your development tools. Maybe you need to fix your IDE.

2-If the new project you created can open the web.xml file, just copy the content and navigate your hard disk until you arrive to the project that gives you trouble and open its web.xml in notepad or similar. 
Try to compare with the other web.xml from the clean project and replace all you think can cause trouble until you fix it. 
Then restart your IDE and try opening the file again.

3-You could also try to clean the project, maybe some old garbage or plugins disturb.

4-Check if your IDE's properties are using the JRE instead of the JDK(Maybe that could be the reason)

5- If the problem remain i think you maybe need to re-install your IDE

Comment: Yes, you are right.At the beginning it's opening using a tool Jboss tools docbook editor(by default). due to that only it's crashing. when i remove/change defaulting that it's working fine.